# powershell how ProcessID based on CommandLine match

Tags: powershell

I want to get process ID based on process commandline.

`$saucelab = gwmi Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'java.exe'" | select CommandLine, ProcessID`

Now there could be many process with Name "java" but I want to find process of the specific process that contains my string.

`$pid = $saucelab | Where-Object {$_.CommandLine -contains "-port 4444"} | select ProcessID`

This does not work

Is there any way to get `processID` based on process `commandLine` match

Answer (score 3):

-contains is an array operator.  Commandline will be a string.  Try using -match instead:

```
$pid = $saucelab | Where-Object {$_.CommandLine -match "-port 4444"} | 
select -ExpandProperty ProcessID
```

see:

```
 Get-Help about_comparison_operators
```

Edit:  When you select one property, you get an object with one property.  If you just want the property value(s), use the -ExpandProperty parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting following output
ProcessID
---------
1760

But I just need process DI